# identifing computers

Tags: cookies, ip

I want to identify visitors computer and track it.  I log visited pages. For example when you visit my webpage i'm generating md5 hash of your ip and send it to you as a cookie .  And then when you browse to my pages i'm logging every page with this cookie's value. So,  when you visit my webpage tomorrow,  i can tell you,  *you visit these pages yesterday :*

But if you change your ip, i'll lost all informations about you.

What can i use instead of IP ADDRESS for identify computers?

Comment: Most people don't like when you track them online.  What justification do you have for this?

Comment: it's just an example,  we can use these method for so many reasons. Also Youtube using a method like this. When you visit YouTube,  it's sending you a weird cookie. Why YouTube sending this?

Comment: It's probably your login session.

Comment: Actually it was not a question. I mean they can track us,  too. I think, I don't need a justification for asking a method.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing, really. HTTP being stateless, the best you can do is try and narrow down a person by the headers in their request. $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] + $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] + $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET'] or something.

This doesn't really work, though, as this information changes even without end users going out of their way.

What [large-scale sites](http://www.google.com/goodtoknow/) do is send you a session cookie. They generally do not go out of their way to track you.